# NodeJS, variable works as expected on local (PC) server but doesn't when deployed to Cyclic.sh

Tags: express

New to ExpressJS, not new to coding.

I have a simple nodejs app that has one variable that is in index.js. There are no other JS files in the application

let listName;

This variable is read from and updated in various route handlers. When running on my local dev machine via nodemon, the variable behaves as expected (sets and reads).

When deployed to Cyclic.SH, the variable value is being "forgotten". As an example the variable is set on a post route, then read again on a get route. When the get route executes, the variable value is blank (I have some console.logging running on the prod server, I read this might not be a good thing to do).

I was expecting the variable to persist. I don't understand why it works in dev but not in prod. I've put more logging in to track the variable value.

I'm confident the code works (or it would have failed in dev). Not sure if it's a specific issue with Cyclic or a noob error. I also have res.redirect the home get route. Not sure if this can cause variables to be forgotten?

This is the route that sets the variable (listName)
[image]

..It then redirects to the home route were the variable listName is used. When run locally, this variable is remembered correctly
[image]

...and here is a log from Cyclic.sh showing the call to list/:list and then the redirect to the home route. You can see that the variable listName is CTG in the list/:list route but when it gets to the home route it is an old value

[image]

My connection methods are nearly identical (I have my connection string hardcoded, I don't use an environmental variable.

Comment: Are you using nodemon in start script?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. it's not something I've deliberately set. How would I determine that?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you are using `nodemon` in start script. Here is an [article](https://www.cyclic.sh/posts/common-mistakes-for-first-time-deploy/) which discourages using `nodemon` in start script.

Go to `package.json` and look for `scripts`

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start":"nodemon index.js"
  }
```

Just remove nodemon and replace with node before pushing the commit:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start":"node index.js"
  }
```

You can test if it is working by running `npm start` directly

Comment: Thanks Kartoos, all I have in the package.json is
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },

Comment: May I know how do you launch your server? Which command do you run to start the server?

Comment: On dev it's nodemon index.js

Comment: I just noticed in the log that that the server is restarting. That would account for the variables being dropped. I'll work out why that is happening first. Thanks for your help

Comment: @FredF you might wanna take a look at the docs: https://docs.cyclic.sh/quick-start#launching-your-own-app. It talks about having "start" script in package.json

Comment: I have improved example in my answer to use "start" script in your scenario... Since you don't have "start" script, just take reference of the final version

Comment: Thanks Kartoos, I have updated package.json and it hasn't made any difference. The rest of the application is working, it's just this one problem. If that start command hadn't been set, I assume nothing on the site would work

Comment: I don't know if it makes any difference, but the application talks to mongodb. I've noticed the server connection code fire multiple times when deployed live (this doesn't happen on my dev environment).  This made me wonder if the server was restarting and killing the variable.

Comment: It could be that server is unable to connect to mongodb.... You need to whitelist the ALL the IP addresses as described [here](https://docs.cyclic.sh/how-to/using-mongo-db). Just search how you can whitelist mongodb IP addresses by setting `0.0.0.0/0` in the configuration. Also take a look the way the mongo db connection code is written in the sample code in the above link

Comment: Also, can you share the cyclic logs that you are seeing if possible (by editing your question)... It might be helpful to debug

Comment: I had already whitelisted the 0.0.0.0/0 IP address for MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

While I couldnt work out why the variable was changing, I realised that I was using a flawed method of retaining variables. Different users can interact with the server, changing the value each time that happens.

I still don't know why the value kept changing (perhaps the server restarted clearing the variable) as I was the only one using the server, but it wouldn't work as envisaged if multiple users used the site. Thanks Kartoos for your insights.

Comment: So after fixing the logic your issue is fixed? 
Also I was thinking to `set NODE_ENV=production` in the terminal before launching the app to see if you can replicate the production bahaviour in your local